# SharePoint online search Rest API returning different totalrows value sometimes without change in data

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, sharepoint-search

I am using SharePoint search Rest API to identify the total rows available for a specific query.
I am getting different value for TotalRows variable sometimes without change in query.
I have used TrimDuplicates:False as well to try to keep the count consistent but the results are different sometimes.

I am using SharePoint online and code is written in SPFX using React.

Same code was working fine earlier and started facing this issue since a day only.

Nothing has changed from the code side.
Please suggest.

Comment: Could you please update with the code used to do the call? Maybe there is some issue with the search index crawler... I would try and do a new full crawl.

Comment: Thanks for the comment..it was indeed some issue with the crawler and it got resolved on its own in the next crawl.